# Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined?

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I am trying to display the data datatables , Tapo there is a problem , please help , for another dicode datatables can run successfully , but in this code do not want the road ?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

This JS

```js
 <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#files').DataTable();
        });
```

```html
table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="files">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>File Name</th>
                        <th>Upload By</th>
                        <th>Upload Date</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php 
                     foreach($files as $f => $file){
                            foreach($permission as $p => $key){
                                if($key['id_files'] == $file['file_id'] ||$this->user->is_teacher || $this->user->is_superadmin ){
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td><a href="'.base_url('dropzone/global_download')."/".$file['file_id'].'">'.$file['file_name'].'</a></td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$file['upload_by'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.date("d-M-Y",strtotime($file['upload_dt'])).'</td>';
                                echo '<td>';
                                if($this->user->is_teacher || $this->user->is_superadmin){
                                echo '<a href="'.base_url('dashboard/permission_file')."/".$file['file_id'].'"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Manage </a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '<td>';
                                    echo '<a href="javascript:_delete_file('.$file['file_id'].');"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete </a>';
                                }
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                            }
                            }
                        }
                 ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: You need the same number of `<th>` elements as `<td>` elements in each row.

Comment: @davidkonrad You should post that as an answer so it's more obvious for any future readers (even though it was such a minor change).

Comment: @ChrisH. - you are more than welcome to answer yourself :) If the question was tagged with javascript or jquery, _and_ OP had higher rep, I guess I would have closed it using the dupehammer (mjolnir) there is so many derivations over this question already. But you are right,  if the question remain it certainly deserves an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datatables large data set Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091881/jquery-datatables-large-data-set-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-mdata)