# Why my DataTable jQuery cant load on my table view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is the code for the script,
but it's not working please help me.

```
 <script>  
  function loading(){
    $("#loading").removeAttr("hidden");
  }

  $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $(".select2").select2();
    $("#example1").DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

This is the code for the script, but its not working please help me.

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/app.min.js"></script> 
<!-- DataTables --> 
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></sc‌ript>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"><‌​/script> 
<!-- Select2 -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>public/plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></sc‌​ript>
```

[image: This image is the function to view my other addition list]

[image: This is the image view of my table]

[this image is the console error please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcPkc.png)

Comment: Try `<?= base_url() ?>/public/...` and then check your browsers network console for errors (404s)

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: check developer console for errors. Do a F12 and check for errors in cosole

Comment: cant load datatables search box on my output table.

Comment: You should check the console "Network" tab to see if these pages are getting called or not.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors, is it loading the scripts or is it 404s? Try adding a slash after `<?= base_url() ?>/`

Comment: please check the image link i posted thankyou

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Datatables large data set Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091881/jquery-datatables-large-data-set-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-mdata)

Answer (score 0):

I Fix it on my Own..

I have a "colspan= 2"  in the view table and i have a extra "td" in my code thanks to all your comment.